# QxJqPlot, decimalMark and thousandsSeparator

Tags: jqplot, qooxdoo

little question:

I add the tickOptions formatString "%'.2f" to my axis, change decimalMark and thousandsSeparator characters at jquery.jqplot.js and jquery.jqplot.min.js, and nothing change. The same decimalMark and thousandsSeparator appears.

If I add the " '.2 " to my format string, the thousands separations and decimal appears, but with the standart characters.

Somebody know what's is wrong? I want use the european "1.000.000,00" format.
Please some little help, thanks.

(sorry my english)

Answer (score 0):

a solution, adding this 2 lines:

```
$jqplot.sprintf.thousandsSeparator = '.';
$jqplot.sprintf.decimalMark = ',';
```

inside the function: (example)

```
    var options = function($jqplot){
        $jqplot.sprintf.thousandsSeparator = '.';
        $jqplot.sprintf.decimalMark = ',';

        return {
            title: "Importe",
            seriesDefaults:{renderer: $jqplot.BarRenderer, pointLabels: {show: true}},
            series: paramet.resultado.series,
            legend: {show: true},
            axes:{
                xaxis:{
                    renderer: $jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: [""]
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: "%'.2f"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var plugins = ['barRenderer', 'categoryAxisRenderer', 'pointLabels'];

    plot = new qxjqplot.Plot(paramet.resultado.dataSeries_total, options, plugins);
```